# NHibernate: Wrong column type: found float, expected double precision

Tags: nhibernate

I have a domain entity class with a property:

```
public virtual double? Result { get; set; }
```

The property is being mapped using the NHibernate 3.2 mapping-by-code stuff:

```
public class SampleResultMap : ClassMapping<SampleResult>
{
    public SampleResultMap()
    {
        Id(c => c.Id,
            map => map.Generator(Generators.Identity));
        Property(c => c.Result, map =>
        {
            map.NotNullable(false);
        });
        // More properties, etc.
    }
}
```

This works fine and the SQL Server 2008 R2 table is created properly with a data type of float.

However, the `SchemaValidator.Validate` call gives this error:

```
NHibernate.HibernateException was unhandled
Wrong column type in Foo.dbo.SampleResult for column Result.
Found: float, Expected DOUBLE PRECISION
```

Looking at the SQL that the call to `SchemaExport.Create` generates there is this definition for the table:

```
create table SampleResult (
        Id INT IDENTITY NOT NULL,
       DateEnteredUtc DATETIME not null,
       ElementId INT not null,
       Unit INT not null,
       ResultText NVARCHAR(50) null,
       [Result] DOUBLE PRECISION null,
       Detected BIT not null,
       Qualifier NVARCHAR(10) null,
       SampleId INT not null,
       Deleted BIT not null,
       primary key (Id)
    )
```

From a quick reading of the NHibernate 3.2 sources it appears that the validator is comparing “DOUBLE PRECISION” to “float”.

Has anyone else seen this? I assume it is a bug but I haven't used the validator before so wanted to find out if I’m doing something wrong.

Comment: In the beginning you said you're declaring it as `double?`. So it is double or float?

Comment: It is a C# `double?` which is stored in SQL Server as a nullable `float` column; these are both double-precision representations. I know, it's confusing, a SQL Server `real` is a C# `float`, which are both single-precision values.

Comment: any solution on that ? I'm encountering the same issue...

Comment: Unfortunately, no. And I tried to post this question to both the nhusers and nhibernate-development Google groups and they were never accepted by the group moderator(s) for posting. Go figure.

Answer (score 3):

I had a similar issue with natively generated IDs on a SQLite DB which was caused because SQLite only supports auto increment on integer columns.

NHibernate had correctly created the ID column as an integer but when it was validating it, it thought it should be an int instead of an integer. Because int just maps to integer on SQLite I just created a new dialect to use integer instead of int and it now works fine.

As DOUBLE PRECISION is the same as FLOAT(53) on SQLServer it might be the same thing, it's seeing float instead of double precision. As a work around you could try changing the dialect to use FLOAT(53) instead:

```
using System.Data;
using NHibernate.Dialect;

public class UpdatedMsSql2008Dialect : MsSql2008Dialect
{
    public UpdatedMsSql2008Dialect()
        : base()
    {
        RegisterColumnType(DbType.Double, "FLOAT(53)");
    }
}
```

The [SQLServer dialect source](https://github.com/nhibernate/nhibernate-core/blob/master/src/NHibernate/Dialect/MsSql2000Dialect.cs#L196) seems to suggest it should work. Definitely looks like there is a bug with the validator though.

Comment: Yes. Double precision maps to float(53) on MS SQL Server. When reading back meta data from the server it reports the data type as float. (https://nhibernate.jira.com/browse/NH-2655)