# C# float, NHibernate, SQL Server 2012 wrong column type found real expected float

Tags: nhibernate, sql-server-2012

Using SQL Server 2012 with a float column I'm having an issue similar to [NHibernate: Wrong column type: found float, expected double precision](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8761193/nhibernate-wrong-column-type-found-float-expected-double-precision), but for a C# single. However, if I register the column type as FLOAT(24) in a custom dialect, I get `Found: float, Expected REAL'.

In short, if I don't do `RegisterColumnType` it finds `float` and wants `REAL`, if I do `RegisterColumnType` it finds real and wants float.

Has anyone seen this issue and been able to fix it?

Comment: The first and second paragraph is in conflict with each other. To make it work, you need to register it as the _true_ native type of SQL Server, not any of the type's aliases.

Comment: I guess that the true native type is FLOAT(24), seeing the linked question and solution for that one. I'll try to check different types and the result tomorrow.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found the answer to my question after looking at NHibernate generated schema on a testing database and reading the SQL server documentation.

My local database had a column of type `real`, the production database had a column of type `float`. `real` is a `FLOAT(24)`, while `float` (as I understand from the documentation) is actually `FLOAT(53)`. This means that the C# type should be `double`, which means that the linked question answers how to deal with it. Decided to change the database column to `real`, after that it works without any dialect modifications.